# Hue service can't start

Tags: cloudera, hue

I'm running a cloudera cluster of 16 machines in university. A few days ago some machines failed and I had to move their hosted service to other machines. One of these service was Hue. I tried to move the server but when I try to launch it, I get thoses messages:

```
Command failed to start: com.cloudera.cmf.service.config.ConfigGenException: Unable to generate config file hue.ini for role with type KT_RENEWER: null

Command failed to start: com.cloudera.cmf.service.config.ConfigGenException: Unable to generate config file hue.ini for role with type BEESWAX_SERVER: null

Command failed to start: com.cloudera.cmf.service.config.ConfigGenException: Unable to generate config file hue.ini for role with type HUE_SERVER: null
```

from its roles.

I did some researches and see similar case with the same errors and the solution was to check again Hue's configuration and set a role for web HDFS, oozie...
But in my case, all roles are set for Hue so I really don't see where does the problem come from...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove and recreate the roles?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything